# returns zero after declaring value in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i am trying to make a gallery viewer on which the webpage shows thumbs of the real images and then when the image is clicked, the original image(with original size) is displayed, the div which holds the html "img" element is changed to visible(else by default it is set to hidden) and meanwhile am trying to get the dimensions of the image so that i can center the images of different dimensions properly acc. to their width and the problem am having is that whenever i click any thumb for the first time after the page is loaded, the statement which gets the width of the image sends 0, and after that when clicking any other image without reloading the page (including the previous one) it shows the previous image's dimension and sometimes it works and sometimes not(mostly doesn't), please help me out. The javascript code is below.

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function() {
$.post(


"loadup.php",
        {
            refer:"yes"
        },function(response){
            $("#gallery_view_tab").html(response);
            initAll();
    });
});

function initAll(){
    $("<div id='imgViewer'></div>").appendTo("body"); //set up image viewer
    $("#imgViewer").insertBefore("#monster_wrap"); //set before monster_wrap

    var thumbimgs = $(".thumbimg");
    for(i=0; i<thumbimgs.length; i++){
        var thumbimg = thumbimgs[i].id;
        var thumbid = '#'+thumbimg;
        $(thumbid).click(loadImgviewer);
    }
}

function loadImgviewer(){
    var imgLink = this.getAttribute("data-link");
    $("<img id='closeImgviewer' src='images/close.png' /><img src='' id='imgview' />").appendTo("#imgViewer");
    $("#imgview").attr('src', imgLink);
    $("#imgViewer").css('visibility', 'visible');
        imgwidth = $("#imgview").width();
        screenwidth = $(window).width();
        var pos = (screenwidth - imgwidth)/2;
        $("#log").html(pos);
        $("#imgview").css('margin-left', pos);

$("#closeImgviewer").click(unloadImgviewer); //set click event handler on image view closer

}

function unloadImgviewer(){
    $("#imgViewer").css('visibility', 'hidden');
    $("#imgview").attr('src', '');
    $("#imgViewer").empty();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [SO]; please take some time to review the [faq] if you haven't already. Additionally I recommend reading [Markdown Editing Help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: @zzzzBov have i done something wrong, but i used the code button for codes

Comment: Not so much, no. Yours is one of the better newbie questions I've read, as at least you posted code and tried to have it formatted. I recommend spending more time on your wall of text that precedes your code. Mostly I was interested in providing resources that you may or may not have been aware of.

Comment: It seems to me that you try to get the image dimensions as soon as you have set the source for the image to be loaded. But the dimensions won't be available until the image has been loaded into the browser.

Comment: @Michi yes you are right, so is there any way to get the dimensions without setting the div to visible?

Comment: The problem is not the div but that you need to wait for the image to be loaded. I haven't tried it but $("#imgview").on('load') should work.

Comment: ok, please please wait, i'll be right back after giving it a try ...

Comment: it worked few times but after that when clicking on any other thumb it doesn't change but when i click on it again it changes...

Comment: atleast give a reply so that i can know that i am talking to someone...

Comment: To notify a previous commenter, mention their user name: eg. @Michi

Comment: @android-guy Sorry... I wasn't in front of the computer. I haven't tried what I commented. Right now I can't look at it any further, but tomorrow I will.

Comment: @Michi ok, but keep checking this post, because i can't sit here for the whole day, i'll be visiting this post often...and am glad that you are trying to help me =) Thx...

Comment: @AndroidGuy I think it would be best if you'd create a Gist with your current code https://gist.github.com/

Comment: @AndroidGuy Finally I rewrote your code... see the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just rewrote your code a little.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.post(
        "loadup.php",
         {
             refer:"yes"
         },
         function(response){
             $("#gallery_view_tab").html(response);
             initAll();
         }
    );
});

function initAll(){
    $("<div id='imgViewer'></div>").appendTo("body"); //set up image viewer
    $("#imgViewer").insertBefore("#monster_wrap"); //set before monster_wrap
    $(".thumbimg").on('click', loadImgviewer);
}

function loadImgviewer(){
    var imgwidth, pos,
        screenwidth = $(window).width();
    var imgLink = this.getAttribute("data-link");
    $("<img id='closeImgviewer' src='images/close.png' /><img src='' id='imgview' />").appendTo("#imgViewer");
    $("#imgview").attr('src', imgLink).on('load',function(evt){
        imgwidth = $(this).width();
        pos = (screenwidth - imgwidth) / 2;
        $("#log").html(pos);
        $("#imgview").css('margin-left', pos);
        $("#imgViewer").css('visibility', 'visible');
    };
    $("#closeImgviewer").click(unloadImgviewer); //set click event handler on image view closer
}

function unloadImgviewer(){
    $("#imgViewer").css('visibility', 'hidden');
    $("#imgview").attr('src', '');
    $("#imgViewer").empty();
}
```

Please try it our. Didn't try it but I think it should work.

Comment: i don't know what should i call you but you are the real programmer and master. thank you very very very very very very muchhhhhhhh.....IT WORKED!!!!!! btw i checked the code there were slight row changes...and a evt in the function parameters can you tell why do we use that because i've seen many people using that and i forgot to tell you, but i tried using load function. but the problem was that it was getting triggered multiple times like clicking 4th time on any image it used to trigger 4 times. and please can you tell why it isn't happening now? once again Thank You Very Much!! =))

Comment: and btw what is github used for? like is it like a localhost or something?

Comment: I'm glad that worked :-) The evt parameter is the event object passed by jQuery... in this case it wasn't necessary as we're not using it... it's just my habit. The multiple trigger was because you attached the event several times to the same object.

Comment: GitHub is a version control system provider. GIST (by GitHub) is to share code online and enables versioning as well.

Comment: BTW... you should accept the answer if it fits you :-) So other people looking for the same problem can see that this answer worked.

Comment: Yes actually I was about to ask how do I close this post as answered?